# Spring Jpa Query: Passing multiple parameters to native query IN clause

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters to a native query in Spring JpaRepository:

```
@Query(value="select pat.id from Pathology pat, PathologySymptom psym "
            + "Where pat.id=psym.patologyId and psym.name IN (:symptoms)",nativeQuery=true)
public List<Long> findIdsBySymptoms(@Param("symptoms") String symptoms);
```

and testing:

```
String symptoms = "vomit";
        try {

            ids = pathologyRepository.findIdsBySymptoms(symptoms);

            List<Pathology> paths = pathologyRepository.findAllById(ids);

            assertNotNull(paths);



        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when I try:
String symptoms = "vomit,nausea";
It returns nothing
I've also tried: "vomit','nausea"; and "'vomit','nausea'"; with same result

The query:

```
select pat.name, pat.id 
from 
Pathology pat, 
PathologySymptom psym 
Where pat.id=psym.patologyId 
and psym.name IN ('vomit','nausea');
```

It returns:

```
  'stomach colic', '4'
```

I have tried also to add mysql replace function but it didn't work:

```
select pat.name, pat.id 
from 
Pathology pat, 
PathologySymptom psym 
Where pat.id=psym.patologyId 
and psym.name IN (select replace('\'vomit\'#','#',''));
```

Query doesn't fail but nothing is returned.

Comment: `and psym.name IN (REPLACE('\'vomit\'#','#',''));` - SELECT keyword is excess.

Comment: When you try with replace in the resulting string the single-quotes are included. That's why there's no match and nothing is returned. I don't get though, why you use replace at all. To pass multiple parameters simply do `WHERE foo IN ('one', 'two', 'three')`